# SQL - concatenate results from 2 tables

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, append

First I need to get exact match like

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title='STRING' ORDER BY x DESC
```

and then append to these results query with LIKE match

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%STRING&' AND title<>'STRING' ORDER BY x DESC
```

and limit these results with maximum of 10 results.

UNION wont`t do the jobs as it sorts all results together and returns wrong order (I need exact match first, then with LIKE)

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title='STRING' UNION
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%STRING%' ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 10
```

The best solution I got is to use multi_query()

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title='STRING' ORDER BY x DESC; ";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%STRING%' AND title<>'red' ORDER BY x DESC";
$Dbi->multi_query($query);
do {
    $sql = $Dbi->store_result();
    while($x = $sql->fetch_array()) {
        ...
    }
} while($Dbi->next_result());
```

but in this case it is not possible to use any mysql inside the inner loop and there also must be better looking solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the UNION, it's accessing the same table twice:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE title LIKE '%STRING&'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN title='STRING' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Just need to add `, x DESC` before `LIMIT 10`. And I prefer this as it is using  'STRING' twice while @gordon-linoff solution is using it 3 times

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one query, by using the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies 
WHERE title like '%STRING%'
ORDER BY title = 'STRING' desc,
         title like '%STRING%' desc
LIMIT 10;
```

The first clause in the `ORDER BY` puts the exact matches first.  The second then orders by the partial matches.  The `WHERE` clause ensures that there is a match of some kind.

Comment: Just need to add `, x DESC` before `LIMIT 10`;

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title='STRING')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%STRING%' ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 10)
```